# WPF DataGrid - Autogenerated Columns - Reusing DataTemplates - Binding Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I was trying to implement a WPF DataGrid that autogenerates its columns and reuses DataTemplates instead of creating DataTemplates that are the same, except for their binding. Therefore I found this project:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate

After trying to implement it on my own I stumbled upon a data binding error with the Datepicker Control. The selected date property of the Datepicker Control is supposed to bind to the Geburtsdatum Property of the Person class.
The CustomDataGridTemplateColumn Class is adjusting the binding of the generated DataGridCell using the binding specified in MainWindow.xaml inside the DataGrid.

Now there is no binding error message, but the property is not set upon choosing a date with the datepicker control. The other autogenerated columns which are not the CustomDataGridTemplateColumn Class, since I did not create a template for them yet, are working just fine. (setter of their respective properties are called).

1.**Person.cs**

```
    public DateTime Geburtsdatum
    {
        get
        {
            return _geburtsdatum;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_geburtsdatum.Equals(value))
                return;
            DateTime old = _geburtsdatum;
            _geburtsdatum = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged<DateTime>("Geburtsdatum", old, _geburtsdatum);
        }
    }
```

2.**CustomDataGridTemplateColumn.cs**

```
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return this.LoadTemplateContent(true, dataItem, cell);
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return this.LoadTemplateContent(false, dataItem, cell);
    }

    private void ApplyBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty property)
    {
        BindingBase binding = this.Binding;

        if (binding != null)
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, property, binding);
        }
        else
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, property, new Binding());
        }
    }

    private FrameworkElement LoadTemplateContent(bool isEditing, object dataItem, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell)
    {
        DataTemplate template = this.ChooseCellTemplate(isEditing);
        DataTemplateSelector templateSelector = this.ChooseCellTemplateSelector(isEditing);
        if ((template == null) && (templateSelector == null))
        {
            return null;
        }
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
        this.ApplyBinding(contentPresenter, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty);
        contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = template;
        contentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
        return contentPresenter;
    }
```

3.**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <Window x:Class="PersonaldatenbankClient.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" 
    xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:PDCModel="clr-namespace:PersonaldatenbankClient.Model"
    xmlns:PDCView="clr-namespace:PersonaldatenbankClient.View"
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DateCellTemplate">
        <DatePicker
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Content,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                           Mode=TwoWay}"
            diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
    <PDCModel:ViewModel></PDCModel:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
    <toolkit:DataGrid 
       ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"
        CanUserAddRows="True"
        CanUserDeleteRows="True"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeRows="True"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        AlternatingRowBackground="Gray"
        AlternationCount="2"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedValues}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        >
        <PDCView:GenerateTemplateColumn.Columns>
            <PDCView:AutoGenerateColumn
            Column="Geburtsdatum"
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateCellTemplate}"
            CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource DateCellTemplate}"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Geburtsdatum}"/>         
        </PDCView:GenerateTemplateColumn.Columns>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

- WPF Inspector Visual Tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqU5d.png

  - DataGridCell (42) Datacontext is Person
  - ContentPresenter (40) Datacontext is Person
  - ContentPresenter (39) Datacontext is Datetime
  - DatePicker(38) Datacontext is Datetime

Comment: I'm not sure exactly if this can help you, but I had a problem in building dynamically Combobox controls bound from code and assigning them a datatemplate and a style, and I've solved creating both Datatemplate and style in XAML and assigning them to the dynamically built control using the (DataTemplate)TryFindResource("myDataTemplate") on the CodeBehind...

Comment: In my case the DataTemplate is defined in XAML, the DataTemplate for the autogenerated column is set in the LoadTemplateContent(..) Function of the CustomDataGridTemplateColumn Class. The difference to your example is, that the DataTemplate here has to have its binding adjusted to get the correct property path for the column that is being generated, which is also where my error lies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but a data template defined in Xaml has a specific field name bound, so if you need to bind the template to different field names probably would be better to generate the template at runtime. The possibility to define a generic template and set the bound field at runtime is a nice feature, but at the moment feasibility is outside my knowledge .

Comment: I doubt that it's not feasible, since it worked in the project I copied the code parts from. I think it is just my binding that is wrongly done.